# How can I make this boxes to have the same width?

Tags: tailwind-css

How can I make these two boxes (I'll have them more) to have same width as the widest one using tailwindcss only classes?

```html
<head>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="flex flex-wrap">
      <div class="max-w-xs border">
        <div class="flex flex-col items-center pt-6 pb-6 px-10">
          <p class="font-bold text-xl mb-5">Company1</p>
          <img class="h-16 mb-5" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
          <p class="mb-2 text-center font-bold">Junior Ruby on Rails Developer</p>
          <p class="text-sm">11500 - 17750 (B2B)</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="max-w-xs border">
        <div class="flex flex-col items-center pt-6 pb-6 px-10">
          <p class="font-bold text-xl mb-5">Company2</p>
          <img class="h-16 mb-5" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
          <p class="mb-2 text-center font-bold">Ruby on Rails Developer</p>
          <p class="text-sm">11500 - 17750 (B2B)</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

```
<div class="flex flex-wrap">
  <div class="max-w-xs border">
    <div class="flex flex-col items-center pt-6 pb-6 px-10">
      <p class="font-bold text-xl mb-5">Company1</p>
      <img class="h-16 mb-5" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
      <p class="mb-2 text-center font-bold">Junior Ruby on Rails Developer</p>
      <p class="text-sm">11500 - 17750 (B2B)</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="max-w-xs border">
    <div class="flex flex-col items-center pt-6 pb-6 px-10">
      <p class="font-bold text-xl mb-5">Company2</p>
      <img class="h-16 mb-5" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
      <p class="mb-2 text-center font-bold">Ruby on Rails Developer</p>
      <p class="text-sm">11500 - 17750 (B2B)</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add class `flex-1` to your divs `<div class="max-w-xs border">`.

```
// git diff

-  <div class="max-w-xs border">
+  <div class="max-w-xs border flex-1">
```